# How can I get my content from a Joomla blog into Blogger or Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, joomla, blogger, atom-feed

I have an old joomla site (v 1.0.11) that I would really like to move over to Blogger or Wordpress.  The commenting on the site uses AkoComment which was an add on module.  Basically, I want to transfer:

- posts
- comments
- users
- css

I haven't found a good tool out there to do this.  What tools would be best to begin to work with this data?  The joomla database is MySql. I would prefer to use blogger as you don't have to pay to host sites on it.  That means though that I don't have direct access to the database.  Blogger takes Atom feeds as import.  The default Atom feed on Joomla will only list the last five posts though, not all, and won't include comments.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way. All your user data in particular will be impossible to migrate due to the completely different ways the two systems would handle passwords and so on.

For the posts though, you probably can migrate them. You'll have to study the format of each platform's database tables and create a query or two to migrate data. For example, something like the below would work. Most of the variables listed here are not the actual ones, you'll need to replace them with whatever's appropriate. The `1` is whatever your ID is in the new system.

```
INSERT INTO wordpress_db.wp_posts ( `wp_author`, `wp_post`, `wp_date` )
SELECT 1, `content`, `posted` FROM joomla_db.jos_content
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an HTTP bot to submit the data from your database or build a megafeed with all your Joombla blog entries. I personally enjoy coding this kind of scripts.